# geth websocket connection stuck open. ethers and web3

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

on my bsc geth node I have 2 bizarre issues.

1. connecting to the jsonrpc over http through a script fails with network errors. same code through node shell works. /shrug
2. web socket connection never closes/terminates. this causes my async functions to NEVER finish.

Assuming that I will never solve #1, I figure the easiest solution is figure out a way to close the web socket. I cannot find any docs on close() or disconnect() in either web3 or ethers.

any suggestions? thanks so much!